# External CSS dosent wokr on body (closed)

Tags: html, css

**Hello Guys**
I have this Code on my website and i want to make the html and body tag 100% height but I am not sure why it dosent get the code from the style.css. Could anybody tell me my error?

```css
<style>
html, body {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Startseite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main-nav.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="test">
      <div class="topnav">
        <a href="">Startseite</a>
        <a href="">Sonstiges</a>
        <a href="">Sonstiges</a>
        <a  href="regestrierung.html">Regestrieren</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not sure if this is the case, but you don't have to add `<style>` tags in the CSS files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove style tag because we only add style tag when we are adding css in html file,but in external file we don't add style tag

Answer (score 2):

When you got external CSS (separate file for CSS) you don't have to enclose your stylings in `<style>` tag.

Simply the style.css file should look like this:

```
html, body {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, body getting 100% width and height, set body background color to see changes